# starting mobile development

Tags: mobile, cordova

I'm starting mobile development for my company, but i don't really know where to start.

I'm a dot net programmer and i know a little bit of java.

I heard about phonegap , http://phonegap.com/start ; It seems to be nice but i'm a little bit confused with the multiplatform html.

You make your code in html, js and css but after that **you need to build it in each platform ?**

Did somebody have a better solution, my company need the app to be on all platform.

I've also heard about web app , you build a website and you can put it as an app, but not sure how it's working.

Thanks for helping me !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If u need apps for all platforms in a short time, use Phonegap.

> You make your code in html, js and css but after that you need to
>   build it in each platform ?

Yes you code in html, js, css and after that build the app around it. Here you have 2 options. Either you can yourself install SDKs for each platform and build apps and release them. This is not that tough as it sounds :)  As you hardly have to deal with any native code. 
 
Or if you dont want to get into SDKs and just want to stick to the html js part of the app then you can use https://build.phonegap.com/ 
 This lets you upload your html js css files to the phonegap build and you can get apps for all platforms from there. 
As for webapps, phonegap is close to a webapp, with an added functionality that you can acces native features like camera, accelerometer and all too. so its fun. :)